# how to extract a subset from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, subset

let's name the following list of lists as `yr = [[90], [91, 92, 93, 94, 95]]` and the following list of single elements as `nm = ['abc', 'abd', 'fgm']` And here are some data in the form of a numpy array, called

```
d  = [ [95, 'abd', 'S', 432235],
       [94, 'abd', 'S', 432231],
       [91, 'abc', 'S', 343433],
       [92, 'abc', 'S', 342433],
       [94, 'abc', 'S', 344433],
       [90, 'abc', 'Z', 343234] ]
```

what I want to do is loop over the each single element of nm as well as list element of yr, and extract the corresponding subsets. For instance, fetch all rows of b the second column of which equals to 'abs' and the first column of which equals to any of the [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95]. How could I do that repeatedly, that is, for each single element of table nm and each list element of yr?

**EDIT:**

This is the output I would expect to be returned:

```
[[90, 'abc', 'Z', 343234]]
[[91, 'abc', 'S', 343433], [92, 'abc', 'S', 342433], [94, 'abc', 'S', 344433]]
[]
[[95, 'abd', 'S', 432235], [94, 'abd', 'S', 432231]]
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the empty lines because you should get 18 elements (6 from yr * 3 from nm).

Then:

```
yr = [[90], [91, 92, 93, 94, 95]] 
nm = ['abc', 'abd', 'fgm'] 
d  = [[95, 'abd', 'S', 432235],
      [90, 'abc', 'S', 343433],
      [90, 'abc', 'Z', 343234]]


yr = [y for y in yr]    
for y in yr:
   for n in nm:
        for dd in d:
            print dd if dd[0] in y and dd[1] in n else '[[]]'
```

Gives:

```
[[]]
[90, 'abc', 'S', 343433]
[90, 'abc', 'Z', 343234]
[[]]
[[]]
[[]]
[[]]
[[]]
[[]]
[[]]
[[]]
[[]]
[95, 'abd', 'S', 432235]
[[]]
[[]]
[[]]
[[]]
[[]]
```

Comment: it should return 3 outputs as we have 3 elements in nm and 1 element in yr.

Comment: But abd is is the only one in nm ... please specifiy your output better otherwise.

Comment: ok you are right. but still, I don't like the way array d is being parsed. I have updated the question. Please have a look. FYI: I also updated the input a little bit.